# Product views datalayer - why does it have a list view?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm rather confused about why a product view would have a list option.

I feel I'm missing out and sort of want to use it.

```
 'click': {
    'actionField': {'list': 'Search Results'},      // Optional list property.
```

source:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce

Answer (score 0):

If you use ehanced ecommerce tracking you get the option to analyze certain productlists. You can find this in Google Analytics under Conversions > E-commerce > Product List Performance. In this Report you will see the field "Product List Name" and "Product List View" as well as "Product List Clicks" and "Product List CTR", this data is being filled when you define a list vor every product impression.

You do this for example to compare two different recommendation lists:

- List A has 100 Product List Views and 10 Product List Clicks so the Product List CTR is 10%.
- List B has 100 Product List Views but only 5  Product List Clicks so the Product List CTR is 5%.

Therefore you could argue that list A works better than list B (very simplified).

Comment: I understand product lists - impressions ctr etc...  but this is on the product view after a list has been clicked. If you landed on the product page why would the product view have a list?     SEE "Measuring Views of Product Details" https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#details

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that because we don't use googles dataLayer scheme, but I don't see the point of it either.

Answer (score 0):

It refers to the list/category of products, where you clicked the product and ended up to the product view.
It is a way to measure, which list brings more traffic, to this product.

In GA4 the same goes for the parameter item_list_name in the view_item event.